# useRef hook for more than 1 input elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am using useRef hook in functional component to show input control when a button is  clicked in react js.I have total 5 input fields which are individually defined.To meet my purpose of triggering input fields in all the  5 input elements i am assigning 5 useRef hooks to 5 constant variables and assigning the ref property to the corresponding input fields. my code is as follows,

```
import React, { useState ,useEffect,useRef} from 'react';
import '../../../assets/styles/modal.scss';
import closeIcon from '../../../images/icons/Icon2.png';
import deleteIcon from '../../../assets/icons/deleteRole.svg';
import { DFPAPIEndpoint, DFPAPIEndpointGalley } from "../../../utils/axios";
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';


export const ConfigGalley = (props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [state,setState]=useState({name:'',fullCarts:null,halfCarts:null,smu:null,stowage:null,firstClass:false,businessClass:false,premEconomy:false,economy:false});
  const [editState,setEditState]=useState({});
  const [carts,setCarts]=useState([]);
  const [selectedGalley,setSelectedGalley]=useState({});
const [buttonStatus,setButtonStatus]=useState(false);
  const[modalFormStatusObj,setModalFormStatusObj]=useState({text:''})
  const [inputFields,setInputFields]=useState(false);
  const [buttonClicked,setButtonClicked]=useState(false);

const inputRef0=useRef(null);
const inputRef1=useRef(null);
const inputRef2=useRef(null);
const inputRef3=useRef(null);
const inputRef4=useRef(null);

const handleReset = () => {
    let timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
      setState((_) => {
        return { ..._, modalFormStatusObj: {text:''} };
      })
    }, 500)
   setState({name:'',fullCarts:null,halfCarts:null,smu:null,stowage:null,firstClass:false,businessClass:false,premEconomy:false,economy:false})
   checkEmptyFields(state);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    showUserRoles(props.airCraft?.galleys);
    checkEmptyFields(state);
  }, [props])

  useEffect(() => {
  if(buttonClicked){
    inputRef0.current.focus();
    inputRef1.current.focus();
    inputRef2.current.focus();
    inputRef3.current.focus();
    inputRef4.current.focus();
  }
  }, [buttonClicked])

  useEffect(() => {
  if(!checkEmptyFields(state)){
    setButtonStatus(false);
  }
  else{
    setButtonStatus(true);
  }

  }, [state])


  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.airCraft){
      setCarts(props.airCraft.galleys);
      setInputFields(checkEmptyFields(state))
    }
    if(props.airCraft.galleys){
    showUserRoles(props.airCraft.galleys);
    }
  }, [props.airCraft])


  const checkEmptyFields=(state)=>{

       for(let i in state) {
        if(i==='name'||i==='halfCarts'||i==='fullCarts'||i==='smu'||i==='stowage'){
            if (state['name'] !== '' && state["halfCarts"] && state["fullCarts"] && state["smu"] && state["stowage"])
            return false;
        }
        }
        return true;

  }


  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    switch (name) {
      case "name":
        setState((_prev) => {
          return { ..._prev, name:value };
      });

        break;
        case "fullcarts":
          setState((_prev) => {
            return { ..._prev, fullCarts:value };
        });
        break;
        case "halfcarts":
          setState((_prev) => {
            return { ..._prev, halfCarts:value };
        });
        break;

        case "smu":
            setState((_prev) => {
              return { ..._prev, smu:value };
          });
          break;
          case "stowage":
            setState((_prev) => {
              return { ..._prev, stowage:value };
          });
          break;

          case "firstClass":
            setState((_prev) => {
              return { ..._prev, firstClass:true,businessClass:false,premEconomy:false,economy:false };
          });
          break;

          case "businessClass":
            setState((_prev) => {
              return { ..._prev, firstClass:false,businessClass:true,premEconomy:false,economy:false };
          });
          break; case "premEconomy":
          setState((_prev) => {
            return { ..._prev,firstClass:false,businessClass:false,premEconomy:true,economy:false };
        });
        break; case "economy":
        setState((_prev) => {
          return { ..._prev, firstClass:false,businessClass:false,premEconomy:false,economy:true };
      });
      break;
      default:
        setState((_prev) => {
          return { ..._prev,name:'',fullCarts:null,halfCarts:null,smu:null,stowage:null,firstClass:false,businessClass:false,economy:false,premEconomy:false };
      });
        break;
    }
  }
  let isError = false,
  updateStatusText="";
 if (modalFormStatusObj) {
   if (('text' in modalFormStatusObj)) {
     updateStatusText= modalFormStatusObj.text;
   }
 }


const getClassCodeEdit=(ob)=>{

  switch (ob?.classCode) {
  case 'fc':
    setState((_prev) => {
      return { ..._prev,firstClass:!state.firstClass,businessClass:false,premEconomy:false,economy:false};
  });
    break;
    case 'bcl':
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev,firstClass:false,businessClass:!state.businessClass,premEconomy:false,economy:false};
    });
    break;
    case 'pcy':
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev,firstClass:false,businessClass:false,premEconomy:!state.premEconomy,economy:false};
    });
    break;
    case 'ecy':
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev,firstClass:false,businessClass:false,premEconomy:false,economy:!state.economy};
    });
    break;
  default:
    setState((_prev) => {
      return { ..._prev};
  });
    break;
}
}

const onConfigClick=async(e,r)=>{
  if(e.target.nodeName!=='IMG'&&e.target.nodeName!=='BUTTON'){
  setSelectedGalley(r)
  getClassCodeEdit(r)
    setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev,name:r.name,fullCarts:r.carts[0].quantity,halfCarts:r.carts[1].quantity,smu:r.carts[2].quantity,stowage:r.carts[3].quantity};
    });
    setEditState((_prev) => {
      return { ..._prev,id:r._id,name:r.name,fullCarts:r.carts[0].quantity,halfCarts:r.carts[1].quantity,smu:r.carts[2].quantity,stowage:r.carts[3].quantity};
  })
    setInputFields(false);
  }
  else{
  setSelectedGalley(r)
  if(r){
     setButtonStatus(true)
     try {
  const resp = await DFPAPIEndpointGalley.delete(`galley/aircraftTypes/${props.airCraft.id}/galleys/${r._id}`);
  if(resp.success){
  setModalFormStatusObj({text:resp.message})
  handleReset()
  setButtonStatus(false)
  props.setState((_) => {
    return { ..._, resetDataSource: true };
  })
  }
  } catch (error) {
  setModalFormStatusObj({text: error.data.message})
  handleReset()
  }
  }
  }

}

const onEditSubmit=async()=>{
  setButtonStatus(true);
    const cartsObj=[
        {
            "id": "full",
            "name": "Full Cart",
            "weight": 0,
            "volume": 0,
            "dimensions": {
                "length": 0,
                "breadth": 0,
                "height": 0
            },
            "quantity":  parseInt(state.fullCarts)
        },
        {
            "id": "half",
            "name": "Half Cart",
            "weight": 0,
            "volume": 0,
            "dimensions": {
                "length": 0,
                "breadth": 0,
                "height": 0
            },
            "quantity":  parseInt(state.halfCarts)
        },
        {
            "id": "smu",
            "name": "SMU",
            "weight": 0,
            "volume": 0,
            "dimensions": {
                "length": 0,
                "breadth": 0,
                "height": 0
            },
            "quantity": parseInt(state.smu)
        },
        {
          "id": "stowage",
          "name": "Misc. Stowage",
          "weight": 0,
          "volume": 0,
          "dimensions": {
            "length": 0,
            "breadth": 0,
            "height": 0
          },
          "quantity": parseInt(state.stowage)
      }
    ]
    let classCode;
  switch (Object.keys(state).map((m,index)=> {if(state[m]===true){return m}}).filter(f=>f!==undefined)[0]) {
  case 'firstClass':
    classCode='fc'
    break;
    case 'businessClass':
      classCode='bcl'
    break;
    case 'premEconomy':
      classCode='pcy'
    break;
    case 'economy':
     classCode='ecy'
    break;
  default:
    classCode=""
    break;
}
let temp= {
  "name": state.name,
  classCode,
  carts: cartsObj
}

    let body=[];
if(temp.name.length){
  body.push(temp,...carts);

}
else{
  body.push(...carts);
}
    const updatedBody = body.map((item) => {
      if (item.name === editState.name) {
        return {
          ...item,
          carts: cartsObj,
        };
      }
      return item
    })

let removeIndex = updatedBody.map(item => item.name).indexOf(selectedGalley.name);
removeIndex>=0 && updatedBody.splice(removeIndex, 1);
    if(!checkEmptyFields(state)){
       try {
     const resp = await DFPAPIEndpointGalley.post(`galley/aircraftTypes/${props.airCraft.id}/galleys`,updatedBody[0]);
     if(resp.success){
        setModalFormStatusObj({text:resp.message})
        setEditState({});
        handleReset()
        props.setState((_) => {
          return { ..._, resetDataSource: true };
        })
        setButtonStatus(false);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    setModalFormStatusObj({text: error})
        handleReset()
  }
    }

    }
  const showUserRoles=(galleyArr)=>{
    const result=galleyArr.map(gal=>{
         return(<div className="form-group galley-modal"  id="one" onClick={(e)=>onConfigClick(e,gal)} style={{overflow:'auto'}}>
           <ul className='list-group' style={{padding: "0 15px"}}>
           <div className='role_card'>
           <div style={{display:'inline-block'}}>
           <p className='role_name'> {<h6 className="subheading-text-medium-title fontLight margLeft8">{gal.name}</h6>}</p>
           {gal.carts.map((_,index) =>
           <li className='list-group-item-role'style={{display:"inline"}} key={index} >
            {<><button className='cart_display_galley'>
             {_.name}<span className='galley_cart_count'>{_.quantity}</span>
             </button>
             </>}

             </li>)}
             <span className='remove_role_icon'>
                <button style={{float:'right'}} id="two" className='mt-4 remove-button-galley' onClick ={(e)=>onConfigClick(e,gal)}>
                <img className="icon-size-role" alt='deleteIcon' src={deleteIcon} />
                </button>
                </span>
           </div>

             </div>
         </ul>
         </div>)
    }

    )

   return result

   }

   const onClickNewGalley=()=>{
    setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev,name:'',fullCarts:null,halfCarts:null,smu:null,stowage:null,firstClass:false,businessClass:false,premEconomy:false,economy:false};
    });
    setInputFields(false);
    setButtonClicked(!buttonClicked)

   }


  return (
    <div className="overlay" role="dialog">
      <div className="dialog sm-scrollbar">
        <div className="dialog__content margBottom48">
          <img className="modal__close_icon" alt='Close' src={closeIcon} onClick={props.onUploadClose} />
          <h2 className="dialog__title subheading-text-medium fontMedium">{props.modelTitle}</h2>
          <hr />
          <button  style={{width:'1rem'}} id='newGalleyAdd' className="done-button subheading-text-medium-title fontLight" onClick={onClickNewGalley}>+ New Galley</button>
       <div className="containe" style={{display:'flex',height:'400px'}}>
        <div className='width50'>
        <div className="">
         <div>
          {props.airCraft &&props.airCraft?.galleys&&showUserRoles(props.airCraft?.galleys)}
         </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div className='width10'></div>
        <div className='width40'>
         <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container">
              <div class="dialog__description_config">
               <label className='margBottom10'>Name *</label>
                 <input
                   id={''}
                   name="name"
                   placeholder='Name'
                   ref={inputRef0}
                   onChange={(e)=>onChange(e)}
                   disabled={inputFields}
                   value={state.name?state.name:''}
                   type={'text'}
                   className='edit-input'
                   />
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container">
              <div class="dialog__description_config">
                <label className='marginTop30' for='fullcarts' >Full Carts</label>
                <input
                  id={'fullcarts'}
                  name='fullcarts'
                  placeholder='Full Carts'
                  ref={inputRef1}

                  onChange={(e)=>onChange(e)}
                  disabled={inputFields}
                  value={state.fullCarts?state.fullCarts:""}
                  type={'number'}
                  className='edit-input-galley'
                  />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container">
              <div class="dialog__description_config">
                <label  className='marginTop30'>Half Carts</label>
                <input
                  id={'halfcarts'}
                  name='halfcarts'
                  placeholder='Half Carts'
                  ref={inputRef2}

                  onChange={(e)=>onChange(e)}
                  disabled={inputFields}
                  value={state.halfCarts?state.halfCarts:""}
                  type={'number'}
                  className='edit-input-galley'
                  />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container">
              <div class="dialog__description_config">
                <label className='marginTop30'>SMU</label>
                 <input
                   id="smu"
                   name='smu'
                   placeholder='SMU'
                   ref={inputRef3}
                   onChange={(e)=>onChange(e)}
                   disabled={inputFields}
                   value={state.smu?state.smu:''}
                   type={'number'}
                   className='edit-input-galley' />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container">
              <div class="dialog__description_config">
                <label className='marginTop30'>Misc. Stowage</label>
                 <input
                   id="stowage"
                   name='stowage'
                   placeholder='Stowage'
                   ref={inputRef4}
                   onChange={(e)=>onChange(e)}
                   disabled={inputFields}
                   value={state.stowage?state.stowage:''}
                   type={'number'}
                   className='edit-input-galley' />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>




          <div style={{marginTop:'2.5rem'}} className='flexRow'>

          <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container">
              <div className='flexRow'>
                <div className={`dialog__description__radio`}>
                <label  class="control control-radio margRight30" for="1">
               <input  id="1" type="radio"
                 name="firstClass"
                 value= {state.firstClass}
                 checked={state.firstClass}
                 disabled={inputFields}
                 onChange={onChange} />
                 <span>First Class</span>
                <div class="control-indicator"></div>
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container">
            <div className='flexRow'>
                <div className={`dialog__description__radio`}>
                <label  class="control control-radio margRight30" for="2">
               <input  id="2" type="radio"
                 name="businessClass"
                 value= {state.businessClass}
                 checked={state.businessClass}
                 disabled={inputFields}
                 onChange={onChange} />
                 <span>Business Class</span>
                <div class="control-indicator"></div>
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container">
              <div className='flexRow'>
                <div className={`dialog__description__radio`}>
                <label  class="control control-radio margRight30" for="3">
               <input  id="3" type="radio"
                 name="premEconomy"
                 value= {state.premEconomy}
                 checked={state.premEconomy}
                 disabled={inputFields}
                 onChange={onChange} />
                 <span>Premium Economy</span>
                <div class="control-indicator"></div>
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container">
              <div className='flexRow'>
                <div className={`dialog__description__radio`}>
                <label  class="control control-radio margRight30" for="4">
               <input  id="4" type="radio"
                 name="economy"
                 value= {state.economy}
                 checked={state.economy}
                 disabled={inputFields}
                 onChange={onChange} />
                 <span>Economy</span>
                <div class="control-indicator"></div>
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
          </div>

</div>

          <div className='dialog_buttons margTop50 floatLeft flexRow'>
            <button className="save-button" disabled={buttonStatus} onClick={onEditSubmit}>Save</button>
            <button className="cancel-button-aircraft" onClick={onClickNewGalley}>Cancel</button>

          </div>
          <div className='margTop24'>
            {Boolean(updateStatusText) ?
          <>
            <div className={ "dialog__statusBlock " + (isError ? 'alert_error' : 'alert_success') }>
              {updateStatusText}
             </div>
           </> : null }
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export const ConfigureGalley = (props) => {
  const onUploadClose = (e) => {
    removeContainerOverlay();
    props.onUploadClose();
  }

  const removeContainerOverlay = () => {
    /**
     * Remove overlay to parent class
     */
    (document.querySelectorAll('.content-container')[0]).classList.remove('modal-overlay-bg2');
  };

  return (
    <ConfigGalley
      modelTitle={props.modelTitle}
      airCraft={props.airCraft}
      setState={props.setState}
      onUploadClose={onUploadClose}


      />
  )
}
```

in the function onClickNewGalley() i am toggling the state of buttonClicked and using useEffect to get the current value of each input fields.But somehow only the inputRef4 is functioning in this implementation.what else could be done?

Comment: You cannot focus on multiple elements, what do you need exactly ?

Comment: Either I don't understand correctly the purpose you want to achieve or maybe you don't know how the focus event behaves.

At the same time there can only be one element that contains the focus, for this reason you can only see the one of the fourth input, because it's the last one but you can't have the focus on all the elements at the same time.

Maybe if you rephrase the question of what you want to do we can help you :)

Comment: i need to focus on all the inputs at the same time of button click

Comment: What do you expect to happen once the user starts typing after the 5 elements are "focused"?

Answer (score 1):

You can only **focus** on one element at a time.

When a text field is selected and accepts input, it is said to have “focus.”